# Term to describe paradox where those with less subject matter expertise can sometimes make better teachers?

Tags: teaching, terminology

A teacher of teachers in a field I'm involved in frequently says:

> the best teachers are often those who only recently learned the material themselves

The rationale for the statement is that someone who has recently learned the material is more intimately aware of the stumbling blocks someone goes through when learning it, and can therefore be cognisant of those when teaching it to other beginners, thus making them a better teacher.

By contrast, someone who has known the subject matter for many decades may have completely forgotten what it was like when first learning the material, and could be therefore prone to impatience, or underestimating complexity or learning time.

#### Question

Does this concept have a name? Or is there any study that backs up the idea that more experienced instructors can sometimes be blind to the most basic concepts in their discipline (since they take them for granted), and therefore (paradoxically) make worse teachers than those with less subject matter expertise?

Comment: I posted a question on whether the curse of knowledge is a real effect, for those interested in discussing that. See [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/163817/40589).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120883/discussion-on-question-by-stevec-term-to-describe-paradox-where-those-with-less). Please read [this FAQ](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4230/20058) before posting another comment. We can only move comments to chat once, but you can use the chat as long as you wish.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

This is called the [curse of knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_knowledge). From Wikipedia:

> The **curse of knowledge** is a cognitive bias that occurs when an individual, communicating with other individuals, unknowingly assumes that the others have the background to understand. [...]
>
> For example, in a classroom setting, teachers have difficulty teaching novices because they cannot put themselves in the position of the student. A brilliant professor might no longer remember the difficulties that a young student encounters when learning a new subject.

Writer and organizational psychologist Adam Grant nicely illustrates the concept in this [article](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/08/25/opinion/sunday/college-professors-experts-advice.html):

> Two decades ago, I arrived at Harvard as an undergraduate excited to soak up the brilliance of professors who had won Nobels and Pulitzers. But by the end of the first month of my freshman year, it was clear that these world-class experts were my worst teachers. My distinguished art history professor raved about Michelangelo’s pietra serena molding but didn’t articulate why it was significant. My renowned astrophysics professor taught us how the universe seemed to be expanding, but never bothered to explain what it was expanding into (still waiting for someone to demystify that one).
> It wasn’t that they didn’t care about teaching. It was that they knew too much about their subject, and had mastered it too long ago, to relate to my ignorance about it. Social scientists call it the curse of knowledge. As the psychologist Sian Beilock, now the president of Barnard College, writes, “As you get better and better at what you do, your ability to communicate your understanding or to help others learn that skill often gets worse and worse.”

Comment: To all those discussing if the effect is real, I posted a separate question about this, see [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/163817/40589).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120882/discussion-on-answer-by-dan-romik-term-to-describe-paradox-where-those-with-less). Please read [this FAQ](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4230/20058) before posting another comment. We can only move comments to chat once, but you can use the chat as long as you wish.

Answer (score 23):

Good teachers are good teachers. Experts are experts. Good teachers aren't always experts and experts aren't always good teachers.

Some of the smartest people I know couldn't teach you how to tie your shoes, and some of the best teachers I know are dumber than a big bag of hammers.

Comment: I've known both types, although a clear majority of those in the two groups combined belonged to smart people who couldn't teach something basic. However, that simply may be due to my having less contact with anyone (whatever their profession) who was "dumber than a bag of hammers". Interesting metaphor, by the way. Was this inspired by the Mark Twain quote ["To a man with a hammer, everything looks like a nail"](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~scottm/cs314/handouts/slides/topic12Recursion.pdf)?

Comment: @DaveLRenfro Really? I'd categorize at least 10% of the PhDs I know as people who couldn't get water out of a boot if the instructions were written on the heel. I worked in construction when I was an undergrad and I don't know what the literary basis is for some of the phrases I learned.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro : Bag of hammers: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/114217/129225

Comment: Title asks for this answer, +1. The body is looking for the word *curmudgeon*.... Knowledge has nothing to do with the ability to teach until you exceed your own boundary. What it does depend on is your ability to relate, and having learnt how to control a classroom way before you burn out into a grumpy old man.

Comment: -1 The question asked for either a name for this concept, or a study that looks into it. This post provided neither. Therefore, it is not an answer.

Comment: *I don't know what the literary basis is for some of the phrases I learned* --- I was expecting to see "bag of rocks", as it's very common (or at least used to be) to refer to someone as dumb as a rock (or dumb as dirt), and there's also the phrase (which also used to be very common) "rocks for jocks" (there are a few other versions for other scientific disciplines whose introductory courses were, for certain U.S. universities, well known as easy ways to take care of the "general college" lab science elective). Since hammers are used for rocks, **(continued)**

Comment: I thought there might be some hidden meaning being conveyed, but I couldn't think of one (other than the teachers in question were just a step up from being dumb as a rock). On the other hand, the term ["big hammer" is often used in math to describe a type of tool used in a proof](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22big+hammer%22+%22proof%22+site%3Amath.stackexchange.com) (when the tool is ridiculously overmatched for the task at hand), and there's also (in math) the often-made observation that some mathematicians are so narrowly focused **(continued)**

Comment: on certain methods of proof that one sometimes says things along the lines that they see every theorem as a possible nail to use their hammer on, and I then wondered if you might be alluding to this (your profile provides no information about your background). As for knowing the phrase was attributed to Mark Twain, I only (vaguely) recollected this after googling it, as I'm used to hearing it in math contexts.

Comment: @BrianDrake The question also called it a 'paradox' which it obviously isn't - hence this answer

Comment: @Libor The question called it a “paradox”, which it obviously *is*. But regardless of what we think of the word “paradox”, the question is still valid, so this post neither explains why the question is invalid nor answers it.

Comment: I thought it was a well-known fact that university lecturers weren't necessarily good teachers anyway. They lecture, not teach.

Answer (score 14):

It is often said but I have never seen firm evidence of it to be true. (I have seen bad teachers hide behind the equally false pretence that "therefore" they must surely be brilliant scientists!)

The biggest confounders are the [Dr Fox effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._Fox_effect#Experiment) and the Dunning-Kruger effect, which lead students to make erroneous assessments as to how well they have been taught.

Teachers who have themselves not mastered the material often fall back on the same coping strategies as poor students: "Do not try to understand this. Just, whenever you see an equation like this, follow these three steps..." Clearly the poor student believes that this teacher speaks their language, but it is far less clear if anyone is learning anything in such an exchange.

This happens mostly with TAs. It is nice to get positive feedback on the module because the TA follows this pattern, but not so nice to see what the students' heads have been filled with, come exam marking time.

Comment: I hadn't heard of the Dr Fox effect before - very interesting!

Answer (score 4):

Another related model is [Dreyfus model of skill acquisition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dreyfus_model_of_skill_acquisition).

The premise being that someone at the Expert level might struggle teaching someone at Novice level since they way they perceive the domain and problems are very different.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a "paradox" unless one assumes - incorrectly - that an expert in a field must ipso facto be an excellent teacher as well. As has been mentioned, teaching is a skill and requires experience and training that a substantive expert in the field may not have. Similarly, an expert in a field (scientific, humanities or otherwise) may not be a good writer. Those are simply different skills. It is commonly - and correctly - stated that lawyers (my field) are often poor writers.  I am not aware of any specific name for this misconception.

Comment: The supposed paradox is that if there are two people who are _equally skilled_ at teaching and one knows more than the other about a certain subject, then — if the claim is to be believed — the one who knows _less_ about the subject would likely be better at explaining it than the one who knows more. This is a stronger statement, and a more counterintuitive one, than just saying that teaching ability is not correlated with subject matter expertise. Now whether this claim is true or not is open to debate, but your answer doesn’t even acknowledge there’s anything surprising being claimed.

Comment: -1 “It is not a ‘paradox’ unless one assumes - incorrectly - that …” I think you can say this about *all* paradoxes. More importantly, this is not an answer to the question posed.

Comment: @DanRomik "The supposed paradox is that if there are two people who are equally skilled at teaching and one knows more than the other about a certain subject, "  That's a possible question with assumptions that someone might ask, but that is not what the OP asked.  The OP asked simply if there is a term to describe the  statement that "the best teachers are often those who only recently learned the material themselves."   And I did in fact answer the question  - no such term afaik. As for whether all paradoxes are based on incorrect assumptions, who knows, but this one certainly is.

Comment: @BrianDrake well, "this sentence is false" is a paradox with no prior assumptions. Good for detecting people who are secretly robots, though.