# Is the curse of knowledge a real effect?

Tags: teaching, reference-request, science-communication

This post is inspired by [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/163747/40589) discussing what is known as [the curse of knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_knowledge) - the ostensible effect where having knowledge about something makes it hard to put yourself in the mental shoes of someone who doesn’t have it, and the corollary effect (which is of clear relevance to the academia setting) that teachers tend to become less good at explaining a subject the more their expertise on the subject grows.

Question: is this effect real? Please cite actual research that supports your claims.

Comment: Thanks for making this question. I will point out that the linked Wikipedia "curse of knowledge" article is mostly *not* about teaching/academia. It's about economics, sales, and negotiations. Only near the end does it add, "It has also been suggested that the curse of knowledge could contribute to the difficulty of teaching...", with a link to a purely speculative essay (and no experimental evidence). Not sure if this observation is better as a comment or an answer.

Comment: I added the reference-request tag as per the question end; hope that's beneficial.

Comment: This reminds of the frog in the well story.

Answer (score 6):

It is worth considering at the outset, that both the extent of knowledge possessed and the ability to teach are subjective and difficult to directly quantify. Therefore, when examining research on the subject, we shouldn't forget that quantification is usually based on indicators loosely correlated to these qualities.

For instance, gauging the extent of knowledge possessed would require some sort of a test (I doubt many academics would subject themselves to the indignity!). Luckily, subject matter knowledge has been tested amongst school teachers, so we have something to go by. Unfortunately, there appears to be a weakly positive correlation, or none at all, between knowledge and ability to teach [1]. Of course, ability to teach is measured by student outcomes, which is also indirect and subject to other factors. A bunch of other markers for knowledge have been  examined in the past, with most exhibiting weak correlations [2].
It is interesting that none of these convey the negative correlation that the 'curse of knowledge' suggests.

Conversely, more recent studies show stronger positive correlations between teaching experience and teacher effectiveness [3,4]. It would then be a fair assumption that the more knowledgeable academics would in general be more senior and therefore have more experience, and thereby be more effective teachers.

Certainly, many of us have personally encountered counter-examples. These encounters probably reinforce the idea of the supposed negative correlation, but are quite clearly a case of confirmation bias. Since the question is about actual research, I think we should just treat the 'curse' as a bit of amusing anectodal folklore.

[1] Byrne, C.J. (1983). Teacher knowledge and teacher effectiveness: A literature review, theoretical analysis and discussion of research strategy. Paper presented at the meeting of the Northwestern Educational Research Association, Ellenville, NY.

[2] Linda Darling-Hammond (2000). Teacher quality and student achievement:
a review of state policy evidence. Volume 8   Number 1, Education Policy Analysis Archives.

[3] https://learningpolicyinstitute.org/product/does-teaching-experience-increase-teacher-effectiveness-review-research

[4] https://www.edweek.org/leadership/new-studies-find-that-for-teachers-experience-really-does-matter/2015/03

Comment: John Hattie's meta-analysis supports teacher subject matter knowledge as a positive influence on achievement, all else being equal. IMO the positive benefit of teacher content knowledge is historically underrepresented in studies because so much instruction could be labeled as bad teaching (relative to hard won, research based strategies).

Comment: I don't think any of this research is relevant - k12 teachers aren't experts in anything other than teaching.

Comment: @Libor-I would argue that the knowledge gap between instructor and student is similar at both levels, and since we are discussing the transfer of knowledge, this research can definitely give us some pointers. For actual academics, as I said, there is still no objective way to establish expertise. I am yet to come across any metric that is unanimously accepted. Correct me if I'm wrong. :)

Comment: In the last two links you have teaching experience - not knowledge of the subject. Obviously teachers that are battle-hardened and know a lot how kids learn will be able to teach them better than someone who barely knows how to silence them. But the first two seem to point in the same direction - effect isn't real and if anything knowledge helps.

Comment: I might remark that the cures of knowledge can't possibly be positing a linear effect, or the best teachers would be those who don't even know the subject, so you would expect to see a small correlation, not a substantial negative one, even if it were true. Correlation's the wrong number here.

Comment: @KevinArlin- Very valid point, thank you. I suppose its safe to say that the tails on both sides of the expertise spectrum would behave significantly different than the middle, and these may damp out a lot of the real effects.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, it is real.** Disclaimer: I’m not a psychologist or an expert on this subject. Nonetheless I’ll provide evidence of several different types that overall strikes me as convincing enough.

1. Scientific research

The curse of knowledge has been demonstrated in experiments in human psychology. The main one I’ve seen cited is Elizabeth Newton’s “[tappers and listeners](https://marshillmedia.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/The-Stanford-Tappers-and-Listeners-Experiement.pdf)” experiment from 1990, where subjects were told to tap out a song, and expressed wildly unrealistic beliefs about the ability of a listener to discern which song was being tapped. This neatly illustrates the effect that we generally overestimate the extent to which other people know what we are thinking and understand our attempts to communicate ideas with them.

Of course, one can criticize these experiments as too specific and not generalizable to other situations. But that criticism will apply to pretty much any widely believed concept or experiment in psychology.

2. Popular science

Steven Pinker, renowned author, cognitive psychologist and linguist, wrote a book called The Sense of Style: the Thinking Person’s Guide to Writing, where he specifically cites the curse of knowledge as a cause for much bad writing and communication of ideas, and analyzes the phenomenon in depth. See [this article](https://stevenpinker.com/files/pinker/files/the_source_of_bad_writing_-_wsj_0.pdf) excerpted from his book.

3. Connection to standard practices in teaching and writing

Some of the advice that people [seem to associate](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ebcpierce/papers/plmw2017-curse-of-knowledge.pdf) with combating the curse of knowledge are common bits of wisdom that are offered all the time and not considered controversial in any way: e.g., people preparing to give a talk are advised to rehearse the talk in front of a live audience (I’ve seen this advice on academia.as many times). Writers are told to have a group of beta readers to read and give feedback on their work (this is standard advice in any creative writing blog or book). All of this shows the general belief in the need for people to get help “getting outside their heads” and viewing their own thoughts from the context of someone else’s point of view. The difficulty we all have of doing that on our own is very closely related to the curse.

4. Personal experience

Anecdotally, I see evidence for the curse of knowledge almost every time I attend a seminar or conference talk, and often when reading papers or textbooks. The general pattern I notice is that people who are immersed in a subject and spend all their time thinking about it generally don’t do a very good job when it comes to explaining the basics of the subject to non-experts. By contrast, people who are newer to the subject seem better able to explain things in a way that’s relatable to a non-expert audience.

There are exceptions of course, and occasionally you see an expert speaker who clearly has spent a good deal of effort thinking about bridging that gap between experts and non-experts and does a very good job. But those are the exceptions that prove the rule.

**Conclusion.** It is easy to dismiss everything I wrote above as insufficiently scientific and/or not specifically relevant to teaching in academia. Those of us who work in technical areas have high standards for accepting something as true, and it’s natural to be skeptical. So, if you are expecting proof for the claim that “the effect is real” at a standard that we are used to in, say, the physical sciences, I’ll acknowledge that it’s going to be impossible to convince you.

However, at the very least the evidence suggests that the curse of knowledge is a widely recognized effect in human psychology, and that related bits of advice about communication are frequently offered by experts and thinkers who have given thought to these sorts of issues. In that sense, I feel completely comfortable in standing behind the claim that yes, the effect is real.

Comment: Honestly, my personal experience is exactly the opposite, and claiming so “boldly” that it’s real seems too far stretched.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano I don’t see what’s so bold about expressing a position that’s identical to that of Steven Pinker and other well-known researchers. But thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano: My own personal experience encompasses both the kinds of things that Dan is writing about, and the exact opposite (by which I assume you mean here that the most knowledgeable people are often the most effective teachers).  My conclusion: the "curse of knowledge" is a real thing, but it doesn't necessarily affect every knowledgeable person equally.

Comment: "But that criticism will apply to pretty much any widely believed concept or experiment in psychology." Well...Replication crisis, anyone?

Comment: @KevinArlin I think you’re missing the point of that comment. Yes, there is a replication crisis, but separately from that, there is the fact that the social sciences are inherently less precise than the exact sciences, so it’s a mistake to judge studies in psychology by the same standard of precision and certainty that one applies in STEM areas. Since many of the commenters here are from STEM and I have seen this issue arise before, I was trying to preemptively address that sort of criticism (with little success so far, it seems).

Comment: Interesting arguments, and well placed disclaimer. I do get a sense of hand-waving, but as you say, this may be the STEM bias. I am more critical of point #3 though; is there anything to suggest that less experienced writers/teachers need this less? What you're stating here is a general truism, but its not clear that it doesn't apply equally to a novice and an expert.

Comment: Even if the effect is real, it could be explained not but ``curse of knowledge'' where an individual's ability to teach declines as they learn more, but by selection bias and selective effort. The deep expertise and ability teach well could be two (mostly) independent skills. Since attaining high level in any skill requires high investment of time, some individuals could spend effort on improving one of them at expense of the other.

Comment: [cont'd] Also, since it is possible to survive in academia without being both a good researcher and good educator, and it is harder to be both, it is not surprising to see many people who are good researchers, but poor teachers and vice versa. These are those that barely made the cut of a very harsh selection process. It would be strange if a majority exceeded the cut by a large margin.

Answer (score 0):

If you take the meaning literally, then yes, it is real. The wikipedia article you point to itself has pointers to some of the research.

But it is a "cognitive bias" not an absolute block. In most situations people speaking to other people have a *tendency* to suppose that the other person shares their context. If we didn't, then we would find communication impossible, needing to give background and context for nearly everything. If the conversation is two-way, with someone from a *similar* background, then it is relatively easy to fill in the blanks in most cases. Generally it works. But Americans traveling around the world often make too many assumptions, leading to the [*Ugly American* effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ugly_American_(pejorative)) when the visitor doesn't understand and refuses to learn. Imagine being the first human on a newly discovered planet of intelligent beings and trying to communicate with no shared context at all. Everything we know is wrong.

But I don't extrapolate this *bias* to assume that teachers become "less good", unless they ignore pedagogy and make unwarranted assumptions about students. A few of us do that, of course, but many of us are conscious of the fact that our students are *not like us* unless they are in doctoral programs and share our context.

In fact, recognizing that the tendency exists can make you a better teacher if you try to remember what you were like when starting out. When I started teaching Tai Chi, as a non-science example, I was very careful to explicitly capture the learning difficulties and misconceptions that I started out with as a practitioner. It made me more sensitive to the issues students had and more patient when they repeated mistakes. That focus made me a better teacher.

I've also written here in a few places about teaching students in CS how to learn. How to take notes. How to summarize. How to make learning deep and real. But first I had to recognize (a) my students are beginners at this, (b) they are all different from one another, and (c) they aren't like me.

So, no research to share, but a lifetime of getting better as a teacher by recognizing a few things and especially, how to be patient while still being insistent with students. Well, that, and being less didactic, too.

And note that for a teacher of some complex subject (not just STEM), the instructor and the student *don't* share important context. Otherwise there is no point to teaching.

Comment: OP asks to cite actual research, and I don't think you did.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni, correct, as I said, mysef. I provide only anecdotal evidence and the research that wikipedia already provides for this and the linked topics.